# Get connection status VPN using dotras

Tags: c#, vpn, dotras

I write code to create and connect to VPN using Dotras in C#. It works very good, but when I write code to get connection status, It doesn't work.
I read Dotras document, and write code like example, but It still doesn't work.

It doesn't show status in multiple line textbox. :(

Please show me, what I wrong. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DotRas;
using System.Net;

namespace VPN1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void btn_create_vpn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string vpnuser = txt_vpn_user.Text;
            string ip_address = txt_IP.Text;
            this.rasPhoneBook1.Open();
            RasEntry entry = RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(vpnuser, ip_address, RasVpnStrategy.Default, RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("(PPTP)", RasDeviceType.Vpn, false));
            this.rasPhoneBook1.Entries.Add(entry);
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }  
    }
    private RasHandle handle = null;
    private void btn_dial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.rasDialer1.EntryName = txt_vpn_user.Text;
        string username = txt_user.Text;
        string password = txt_pass.Text;
        this.rasDialer1.PhoneBookPath = RasPhoneBook.GetPhoneBookPath(RasPhoneBookType.AllUsers);
        try
        {
            this.rasDialer1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            this.handle = this.rasDialer1.DialAsync();
            this.btn_disconnect.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    private void rasDialer1_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.txt_status.AppendText(e.State.ToString() + "\r\n");
    }

    private void rasDialer1_DialCompleted(object sender, DialCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Cancelled)
        {
            this.txt_status.AppendText("Cancelled");
        }
        else if(e.TimedOut)
        {
            this.txt_status.AppendText("Timeout");
        }
        else if(e.Connected)
        {
            this.txt_status.AppendText("Connection successful");

        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            this.txt_status.AppendText(e.Error.ToString());
        }
        if(!e.Connected)
        {
            this.btn_disconnect.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void btn_disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.rasDialer1.IsBusy)
        {
            this.rasDialer1.DialAsyncCancel();
        }
        else
        {
            RasConnection connection = RasConnection.GetActiveConnectionByHandle(this.handle);
            if(connection!=null)
            {
                connection.HangUp();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what part of your code doesnt work as expected?

Comment: Sorry sir, I forget. It is rasDialer1_StateChanged and rasDialer1_DialCompleted

Comment: does those events not fire?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't show any status in textbox

Answer (score 1):

If the events are not firing, the issue might be that the Events are not set in the events section in the properties window of the rasDialer1 control you added to the form (Form1). Using Visual Studio, Enter the design view, click on the rasDialer1 control which reveals the properties of the RasDialer you added, then navigate to events section (marked with a lightening icon) and then set the StateChanged and DialCompleted events.

OR

You can do all this from code simply by

```
rasDialer.StateChanged += rasDialer1_StateChanged;
rasDialer.DialCompleted += rasDialer1_DialCompleted;
```

somewhere in the Form1() constructor, where rasDialer1_StateChanged and rasDialer1_DialCompleted are the event handlers in your code.

I'm also anticipating a potential error within your code where accessing UI controls in those event handlers will get you a `Cross-thread operation not valid` error since they are called from an async operation `this.rasDialer1.DialAsync();`

The right way of accessing controls from methods called from another thread is below ...

```
textbox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textbox1.text = "my string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using dial instead of dialAsync

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
    {

        File.WriteAllText("your rasphone.pbk  path","")//Add
        string vpnuser = txt_vpn_user.Text;
        string ip_address = txt_IP.Text;
        this.rasPhoneBook1.Open();
        RasEntry entry = RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(vpnuser, ip_address, RasVpnStrategy.Default, RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("(PPTP)", RasDeviceType.Vpn, false));
        this.rasPhoneBook1.Entries.Add(entry);
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.